# error: 'SetPosition' was not declared in this scope

Tags: scope, arduino, undeclared-identifier

Arduino: 1.6.9 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Mega ADK"

In file included from C:\Users\Disheet\Downloads\humanoid_1\humanoid_1.ino:1:0:

C:\Users\Disheet\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ax12v2/ax12.h:66:23: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef unsigned char boolean'

typedef unsigned char boolean;

```
                   ^
```

In file included from sketch\humanoid_1.ino.cpp:1:0:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:117:14: error: 'boolean' has a previous declaration as 'typedef bool boolean'

typedef bool boolean;

```
          ^
```

C:\Users\Disheet\Downloads\humanoid_1\humanoid_1.ino: In function 'void setup()':

humanoid_1:5: error: 'SetPosition' was not declared in this scope

SetPosition(1,0);////id,posiotin 0-1023

```
              ^
```

C:\Users\Disheet\Downloads\humanoid_1\humanoid_1.ino: In function 'void loop()':

humanoid_1:13: error: 'SetPosition' was not declared in this scope

SetPosition(1,512);

```
                ^
```

Multiple libraries were found for "ax12.h"
 Used: C:\Users\Disheet\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ax12v2
 Not used: C:\Users\Disheet\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Bioloid
exit status 1
'SetPosition' was not declared in this scope

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: In StackOverFlow, you should explain your question and use a title to explain your question, please modify the title.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to find `typedef unsigned char boolean;` in your library and change it to match the version in Arduino.h.

`boolean` is already a typedef in Arduino.h, and it is a `bool` ,not `unsigned char`.

In the AX12 library search for this:
https://github.com/7Robot/Arduino/blob/master/AX12/libraries/ax12/ax12.h#L66

And change it to `typedef bool boolean;`.

This was updated a while ago, so your IDE version is newer than the AX12 library.

Comment: you might try to replace both typedefs by an  #include <arduino.h>, if you want to update that library. But that might cause more issues ;)